# What trains are now running from Colombo to Galle in Sri Lanka and how can I prebook?

Tags: trains, sri-lanka

We are travelling from Colombo to Galle in April. We would like to take a train, either Exporail or Rajhastani.

Are there any first class carriages operating? Can we prebook?

Answer (score 2):

A Google search leads the visitor to the [website](https://eservices.railway.gov.lk/schedule/searchTrain.action?lang=en) of Sri Lanka Railways (SLR).

A simple search performed for 1st April from Colombo fort to Galle shows 10 results:

[image]

We have an existing thread that answers your second question: [How to book a train ticket in Sri Lanka in advance?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57877/how-to-book-a-train-ticket-in-sri-lanka-in-advance)